# Заменить маленькие буквы на большие, а большие на маленькие

Tags: javascript

Хочу использовать цикл

```
var letters = "This iS a TeSt sTring";
for (i = 0; i++; i < str.length) {
    if (letters[i] === letters[i].toLowerCase())
         ...
}
```

дальше затрудняюсь. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно написать код.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
function flipCase(str) {
  var chars = str.toUpperCase().split("");
  for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    if (chars[i] == str[i])
      chars[i] = chars[i].toLowerCase();
  }
  return chars.join("");
}

var letters = "This iS a TeSt sTring Щф";
var result = flipCase(letters);
console.log(letters);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `split` лишний.

Answer (score 4):

Если допустить, что буквы могут быть любые (не только латиница), возможно несколько вариантов, например:

```js
const letters = "This iS a TeSt sTring";
let inverseLetters = '';

function invertLetter(letter) {
  return letter === letter.toLowerCase() ?
    letter.toUpperCase() :
    letter.toLowerCase();
}

for (const letter of letters) { inverseLetters += invertLetter(letter); }
console.log(inverseLetters);

inverseLetters = [...letters].map(invertLetter).join('');
console.log(inverseLetters);

inverseLetters = letters.replace(/./gu, invertLetter);
console.log(inverseLetters);
```

Если поддерживаются [Unicode property escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes), можно так:

```js
const letters = "This iS a TeSt sTring";
let inverseLetters = '';

function invertLetter(letter) {
  if (/\p{Lu}/u.test(letter)) return letter.toLowerCase();
  if (/\p{Ll}/u.test(letter)) return letter.toUpperCase();
  return letter;
}

for (const letter of letters) { inverseLetters += invertLetter(letter); }
console.log(inverseLetters);

inverseLetters = [...letters].map(invertLetter).join('');
console.log(inverseLetters);

inverseLetters = letters.replace(/\p{L}/gu, invertLetter);
console.log(inverseLetters);
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
console.log("This iS a TeSt sTring".replace(/./g, c => {
  var u = c.toUpperCase()
  return c === u ? c.toLowerCase() : u
}))
```

Comment: Да, это мне определенно нравиться, никакой зависимости от языка.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var letters = "This iS a TeSt sTring"
console.log(
  letters.replace(/([A-Z])|([a-z])/g, (_, u, l) => (
    u ? u.toLowerCase() : l.toUpperCase()
  ))
)
```

Comment: Работает только с латиницей.

Comment: @Qwertiy никто не мешает добавить любые символы. Я ведь подсказал решение на 2 строки с максимальной скоростью. `RegExp` отработает куда быстрее разборов на всякие массивы.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg измеряли?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q  - нет, хотя тут используется callback, поэтому согласен, может и дольше.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg а я не оспариваю, интересуюсь...

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log('HhH'.split('').map(k => k === k.toUpperCase() ? k.toLowerCase() : k.toUpperCase()).join(''));

console.log('This iS a TeSt sTring'.split('').map(k => k === k.toUpperCase() ? k.toLowerCase() : k.toUpperCase()).join(''));
```